# Python Get Mouse position in a cron script

Tags: python, cron

I am using python3 and I am able to get the mouse position using the following codes in Centos 7:

```
from Xlib import display
data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
data["root_x"], data["root_y"]
```

However, when I run the script using crontab, it shows the following exception:
Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""

Is there a way I can get the mouse position using python and cron job?

Comment: With a cron job it will be hackish, assuming you can make it work at all. I would try to have a look at per-user systemd jobs. Systemd can run timer-type slices which are a superset of cron's features. And processes run by per-user systemd normally have access to display and security cookie for accessing the X server (depends on distro setup).

Answer (score 0):

It is because the environment variable `DISPLAY` is not set properly during execution of your python script.  Try adding the following line to the beginning of your python script, for example:

```
import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'  # the value should match your setting
```

Comment: On a single-user system, this has some chance of working correcly some of the time.  In the general case, there is no guarantee that `:0.0` is owned by the user whose `crontab` is being executed, or that there is a `DISPLAY` (the user might not be logged in with an interactive session at all).  On a properly secured system, there will also be a privilege issue -- programs outside of the interactive session should basically not be able to mess with the private parts of the interactive session.